# applying change to a text using css

Tags: html, css

I need help once again. I am having a problem doing some change in my text in html and css. May I ask what's wrong with my method of calling the class given which is "title". I can't do any change such as color, font weight etc.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}


/*bluebar on top css*/

.bluebar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #1C3879;
}


/*Header logo cart login css*/

header .mlogo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

header .logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40%;
}

.iconbar {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.shopicons {
  padding: 14px 15px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.shopicons a {
  padding: 13px;
  color: #607EAA;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.shopicons i {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

.shopicons a:hover {
  color: #1C3879;
}


/*navigation bar css*/

.mainnav {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.mainnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #607EAA;
}

.mainnav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.mainnav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  color: #EAE3D2;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: 600;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.mainnav ul li ul.dropdown li {
  display: block;
}

.mainnav ul li ul.dropdown {
  width: 100%;
  background: #607EAA;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}

.mainnav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #1C3879;
}

.mainnav ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
}


/*image slider top css*/

.slidecontainer {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}


/*brands*/

.title {
  color: red;
}

.brands-wrap {
  margin: 50px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.brands-in {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.brands-in ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.brands-in ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.brands-in ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.brands-in ul li img:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: .5s;
}

.brands-in ul li img:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: .5s;
}

.brands-in ul li:hover img:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: .5s;
}

.brands-in ul li:hover img:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Main Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./cssfiles/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<div class="bluebar">
</div>

<!--Header Part (header.php)-->
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>


  <body>
    <!--navigation bar-->
    <div class="mainnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop now</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">All Brands ▼</a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Nike</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Adidas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Skechers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fila</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Balance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Under Armour</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </div>

    <!--Image Slider - Top-->
    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <div class="swiper">
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <!-- Slides -->
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/1.jpg"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/2.jpg"></div>
          <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="slideshow/3.jpg"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- If we need pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--Brands section-->

    <div class="titlecontent">
      <p class="title">Our Brands</p>
    </div>
    <div class="brandcontainer" id="brands">
      <div class="brands-wrap">
        <div class="brands-in">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <!--Nike logo-->
              <img src="./images/nike1.png">
              <img src="./images/nike2.png">
            </li>
            <li>
              <!--Adidas-->
              <img src="./images/addi1.png">
              <img src="./images/addi2.png">
            </li>
            <li>
              <!--New Balance-->
              <img src="./images/nb1.png">
              <img src="./images/nb2.png">
            </li>
            <li>
              <!--Underarmour-->
              <img src="./images/ua1.png">
              <img src="./images/ua2.png">
            </li>
            <li>
              <!--Fila-->
              <img src="./images/fila1.png">
              <img src="./images/fila2.png">
            </li>
            <li>
              <!--Skechers-->
              <img src="./images/ske1.png">
              <img src="./images/ske2.png">
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!--Footer part (footer.php)-->


    <!--Script for image slider-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        spaceBetween: 30,
        centeredSlides: true,
        // Optional parameters
        autoplay: true,
        // If we need pagination
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,
        },

        // Navigation arrows
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
      });
    </script>
```

This files is actually the test file because when I am trying to do this in my main files, it doesn't really let me change the color or anything related to text.

My expected output is of course make the "Our Brands" paragraph become red.

Comment: Should work, but if you have another more specific rule (check the debugger) then it'll get overridden.

Comment: The code above will work as expected, so something else must be overriding `.title` definitions. Post the original code so ppl can have a look... [reprex]

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow, where did you define your CSS code ? I mean in an external file or in `<style></style>` tag ? also I recommend to make a space between the word `.title` and the `{` because some engines can not parse it correctly

Comment: Please, do the updates as previously suggested. Give us the way you're linking this css file with your .html file, also check if you have any other css files which are applied onto this

Comment: I edited it thank you.  sorry my code isnt that well good yet. still practicing

Comment: That isn't a minimal reproducible example. It is neither minimal not reproducible.

Comment: Its already okay. Yes the caching thingy is the problem. Because I have tried this method of calling class before and now its okay.

Answer (score 0):

As this user didn't provided enough info (in the time of me writing this answer, I've written it accordingly to the info provided in that time)

There are various reasons why the CSS isn't working.

**Incorrect file linking**

I think above is self explanatory

**Browser Caching**

Browsers will often cache, or temporarily store, resources from websites you visit in order to improve load speed. Some sites will also use plugins for additional caching. Often when you don’t see your custom styles on your site, it’s because the browser or other system has cached an older version of your site.

**Invalid CSS Format**

CSS must be written in a specific format in order for a browser to understand it. There are many online tools to check that your CSS is valid, including W3School’s CSS Validator. This is an excellent option if you have a lot of custom CSS and at least a little previous experience creating CSS.

**CSS Specificity**

Since all themes and most plugins contain their own sets of styles, you will often find that your custom styles must “compete” against existing styles. In such situations, the more specific CSS selector will almost always win out over a less specific selector.

Way to go about CSS specificity is
**Using !important in CSS**

In some situations, you can force a less specific snippet of CSS to work by including the !important rule before the semicolon. It’s always better to try a more specific selector (as described above) first, but sometimes this can offer a quick fix.

Comment: also with important thing